# Editing my loop-page.php causes posts to show on all pages

Tags: templates

I am working on a project where I needed to list out blog posts when I hit a particular page. Originally I was just using the base code in my `loop-page.php` file. To do that I was using:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

This worked great but then I had to do some customizing when displaying the posts. I haven't done this before, so I found this code:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'post'
));
                
if ($query->have_posts()) { ?>
  <?php while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="news-post"> 
      <a href="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>"><p class="news-title"><?php echo get_the_title();?></p></a>
      <p class="news-date"><?php echo get_the_date();?></p>
      <p class="news-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt();?></p>
    </div>
  <?php
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This was exactly what I needed for my blog page, but when I went to click to go to my homepage, I still see the same posts layout. I imagine it's because of the if logic, but I'm not sure where to turn. Is this the proper approach or am I off the mark? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Is it true that `loop-page.php` is a template part and the code from the question resides there? Also, what's the difference between your 'blog page' and 'homepage'? You have to [edit the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/401890/edit) to add more information on how your site is organized. The code in the question does the proper thing — lists all posts in a right manner.

Comment: @MaxYudin Thanks for the response. To answer your questions, `loop-page.php` is a template part and all code from this question resides there. As far as a difference between the blog page and homepage I'm not too sure. To be even more honest, I'm not even sure what would be considered the blog page. I think I have to go back a few steps to learn those differences. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If I understood right, some of your _page templates_ use the same _template part_ (_'loop'_). It leads to the same result on different pages (pages using different templates). Try to recon which template renders which page. Maybe you have to create one either for blog or front. To recon the template file name use `echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true )}` right after the `$query->the_post();`.

Comment: @MaxYudin Hey big thanks for your follow up response. Long story short I was building off of the wrong template. I needed to be working with `loop-archive.php` and doing this I was able to get what I needed. Thanks again for the tip!